# How to sum "any three elements" in a tuple in F#

Tags: f#

I recently started learning how to program in F# and I have an assignment that is giving me some serious headaches.

I have to make a function that takes two arguments, an integer and a five element tuple of integers, and returns true if the sum of any three elements of the tuple is greater than the first argument, else false.

I started designing my code this way

```
{
let t3 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
let intVal = 1
let check intVal t3 = 
for t3
    if (*sum of any three elements*) > intVal then true
    else false
}
```

but at this point I am stuck and do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy way define - sort elements of tuple and compare with sum last three elements (ascending sort) :

```
let inline isAnyThreeGreaterThan2 limit (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) = 
    [x1;x2;x3;x4;x5] |> List.sort |> Seq.skip 2 |> Seq.sum > limit
```

Example:

```
isAnyThreeGreaterThan2 15 (1, 2, 5, 5, 5) |> printfn "%A"
isAnyThreeGreaterThan2 14 (1, 2, 5, 5, 5) |> printfn "%A"
isAnyThreeGreaterThan2 15 (1, 2, 5, 5, 6) |> printfn "%A"
isAnyThreeGreaterThan2 15 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) |> printfn "%A"
isAnyThreeGreaterThan2 12 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) |> printfn "%A"
isAnyThreeGreaterThan2 11 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
false
true
true
false
false
true
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7XR1ZA

Comment: Nice out-of-the-box thinking! I wish I had thought of that :)

Answer (score 4):

It could be solved by converting the tuple into an array, getting the possible combinations out of it, summing those combinations and then verify if the any of the sums is greater than your parameter

```
(1,2,3,4,5) 
|> Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields 
|> Array.toList 
//Implementing this is left as and exercise to the reader
|> combinations 3 
//converts the obj list as a int list and then sums the elements
|> List.map (fun x -> x |> List.map unbox<int> |> List.sum) 
//Verifies if any sum is greater than intVal
|> List.exists (fun x -> x > intVal)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use any of this. I am only permitted to use "match" to do this and this is where my problem comes from

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
let cross3 l1 l2 l3 =
    [
        for x in l1 do
            for y in l2 do
                for z in l3 do
                yield x, y, z ]

module Tuple3 =
    let distinct (x, y, z) =
        let l = [x; y; z]
        l |> List.distinct |> List.length = l.Length

    let snd (x, y, z) = snd x, snd y, snd z

    let inline sum (x, y, z) = x + y + z

let inline isAnyThreeGreaterThan limit (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) =
    let l = [x1; x2; x3; x4; x5] |> List.indexed
    let legalCombinations =
        cross3 l l l
        |> List.filter Tuple3.distinct
        |> List.map Tuple3.snd
    legalCombinations |> List.exists (fun t3 -> Tuple3.sum t3 > limit)
```

Since this is an assignment, I'll leave it as an exercise to understand what's going on, but here's a sample FSI session:

```
> isAnyThreeGreaterThan 15 (1, 2, 5, 5, 5);;
val it : bool = false
> isAnyThreeGreaterThan 14 (1, 2, 5, 5, 5);;
val it : bool = true
> isAnyThreeGreaterThan 15 (1, 2, 5, 5, 6);;
val it : bool = true
> isAnyThreeGreaterThan 15 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);;
val it : bool = false
> isAnyThreeGreaterThan 12 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);;
val it : bool = false
> isAnyThreeGreaterThan 11 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);;
val it : bool = true
```